# How to avoid repetition with same params

Tags: java

I am trying to find out a way to avoid the kind of repetition below

```
try {
    await().pollInterval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollDelay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) 
        .atMost(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(() -> {
            // 1. methods in here
        });
} catch (final Exception e) {
    //TODO: can be handled internally
}
```

It happens in several places in my code, and I want to make it less repetitive, but I am not finding a way to do so. I thought about lambdas, but I don`t know much about it nor if it would fit in here.

Inside of it can be many different things, it is not the same for all nor they have the same inheritance.

Comment: Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts. The obvious way is to create a new method, which is called by the different places you have.

Comment: That is the point, I am not being able to find a way to do so, that I why I came here. Create a method that could do it or reused with a set of rules is easy, but a method with a preset of these commands that receive free stuff in the middle, this I am not finding a way to do so. Still struggling and thinking about how to do it

Comment: Just wrap this code into a method accepting a `Runnable`. And in the place of your commented-out text, just write `runnable.run()`.

Comment: @MCEmperor I think your answer is in the same line as @oleg, I`ll try it out. Thank you

Comment: Thank you @MCEmperor, all good, dully noted and learned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    awaitUntil(() -> {
        // payload 1
        return true;
    });

    awaitUntil(() -> {
        // payload 2
        return true;
    });
}

public static void awaitUntil(Callable<Boolean> conditionEvaluator) {
    try {
        Awaitility.await()
                  .pollInterval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                  .pollDelay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                  .atMost(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                  .until(conditionEvaluator);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //TODO: can be handled internally
    }
}
```